# After updating TestFlight Showing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to install app from TestFlight which is as shown is the image:

[image]

And after clicking on install it not install.

Comment: I think you have install previous version of this app in your iphone?

Comment: @Birendra But I remove it and trying to install.But it not getting istall

Comment: just delete old app and install Again ..or may be your app not Uploaded propery on testflieght..

Comment: @VarinderSingh I deleted app but it not getting install.

Comment: you have change the version of uploaded app for TestFlight?

Comment: first check your certificates ,Check device udid and upload again.. sometimes it is not upload proper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestFlight alert while testing update: You already have this app installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539534/testflight-alert-while-testing-update-you-already-have-this-app-installed)

Comment: @Muju check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539534/testflight-alert-while-testing-update-you-already-have-this-app-installed/34219081#34219081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert with warning about possible lose of data is being displayed always for any app being installed from `TestFlight`.
This was true for any of multiple apps I have tried.
`identifierForVendor` changes when **overwriting** app with `TestFlight` build.

When you have App Store version of the app installed and overwrite it with build from `TestFlight`, result of `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!` changes

In my case unexpected change of `identifierForVendor` was causing "loss of data" which wasn't actual loss of data, but it is happening only for `TestFlight` builds which you cannot **debug**, so it was hard to find the issue.